# Can a rake task use a controller's "create" method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rake task which creates Events from Purchases, provided the Purchase has a specific date attribute.

The rake task code is:

```
namespace :events do

  desc "Create events from purchases."
  task purchases: :environment do

    purchases = Purchase.all

    purchases.each do |purchase|
      begin
        ## SUMMARY VARIABLE
        vendor = purchase.vendor.name
        order_number = purchase.order_number
        est_ship_date = purchase.estimated_ship_date
        purchase_summary = "Est. ship date: #{est_ship_date} #{vendor} PO ##{order_number}"

        ## DESCRIPTION VARIABLE
        tradegecko_url = purchase.tradegecko_url
        description = "#{vendor} PO ##{order_number} Estimated ship date: #{est_ship_date}. #{tradegecko_url}"

        ## START_DATE VARIABLE
        start_date = purchase.estimated_ship_date

        ##END_DATE VARIABLE
        end_date = start_date

        unless purchase.estimated_ship_date == nil
          event = Event.find_or_initialize_by(summary: purchase_summary)
          event.update_attributes(
            summary: purchase_summary,
            description: description,
            start_date: start_date,
            end_date: end_date
            )
          pp purchase
        end
      rescue NoMethodError => e
        puts "#{e.inspect} #{purchase.inspect}"
      end
    end
  end
```

When I run the rake, the Event is created in my Events table, which seems to work fine, except that in my Events Controller "create" method I have an "if @event.save" call that pushes the event to my google calendar, then grabs the event_id from the newly created google calendar event and saves it in my database. This works perfectly if I manually create a new event, but not when new events are created from the rake.

The events_controller.rb "create" method:

```
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event successfully created.' }
        format.js   {}
        format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    if @event.save

      gcal_event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
        summary: @event.summary,
        description: @event.description,
        start: {
          date: @event.start_date
        },
        end: {
          date: @event.end_date
        }
      })

      @cal_service = GoogleCalendarService.new
      @cal = @cal_service.calendar

      result = @cal.insert_event(GoogleCalendarService::CALENDAR_ID, gcal_event)

      @event.calendar_event_id = result.id
      @event.save
    else
      render :nothing => true
    end
  end
```

Is there any way to make sure that the controller's "create" method is called when I run the rake task?

Comment: you can add the Google calendar logic in the rake task for `event` object.

Comment: The best way is to move the `Google calendar logic` into Model using after_save call back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **`after_create`** rails callback in the `Modal` to create the `google_calendar` logic, removing it from controller.

**This also helps you to reduce the code as rails follows DRY concept. Where ever your event gets created, the model code runs.**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

after_create :google_calendar
    .
    .
    .
    .

  private
    def google_calendar
        gcal_event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
            summary: self.summary,
            description: self.description,
            start: {
                date: self.start_date
            },
            end: {
                date: self.end_date
            }
        })

        @cal_service = GoogleCalendarService.new
        @cal = @cal_service.calendar

        result = @cal.insert_event(GoogleCalendarService::CALENDAR_ID, gcal_event)

        self.calendar_event_id = result.id
        self.save
    end
end
```

**This method runs whenever your object gets saved. ( No matter whether it is from a controller or a rake task)**

So, your controller action will be,

```
def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event successfully created.' }
        format.js   {}
        format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end
```

[Here is a documentation of the various CallBacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Comment: Yeah I figured I would have to move it to the Model. I guess I was just being a lazy coder and wondering if it was possible to trigger the controller methods. Thanks.

Comment: @NeyLive, you can accept my answer, if you find it useful. :)